# VoiceOver in UITextView: read paragraph at a time

Tags: ios, uitextview, voiceover

I'm developing a newspaper, magazine and book reading app for the visually impaired. Users of the app want VoiceOver to read the text in the UITextField a paragraph at a time and not read everything in one go. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446459/how-to-read-a-uitextview-paragraph-by-paragraph-using-voiceover ? Look for `UIAccessibilityContainer` which seems to be the solution.

Comment: Yes, I saw that post but I feel that the answer is too vague.

Comment: "Utilizing the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol" indeed completely answers the question "How can this be accomplished?". Perhaps it is your question that is too vague. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple actually. Any time you have a new paragraph, utilize a new `UITextField` view. This causes the "default" behavior to be scanning one paragraph of text at a time, which is very intuitive. While still allowing the "Line by Line" rotor setting to function as one line at a time. Which the `UIAccessibilityReadingContent` protocol would solution would not do.

NOTE: Another way to accomplish the same effect as multiple `UITextFields` is to utilize the `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol to create synthetic Accessibility Views only scene by VoiceOver. Turning your one larger `UITextField` container, into multiple `UIAccessibilityElements` for accessibility purposes.

Though, if you have paging behavior, you SHOULD utilize the paging feature of this protocol. THIS would allow a user to read your collection of multiple `UITextFields` one page at a time.

To summarize, this approach allows users to:

- Read One page at a time (by utilizing `UIAccessibilityReadingContent`)
- Read one paragraph at a time (default behavior, with one paragraph per `UITextField`)
- Read one line at a time (rotor: Line by Line)
- Also, other rotor settings (Word and Character)

Seems solid to me!

Comment: Your solution certainly seems feasible. Because I will also need to track and remember where the tts was interrupted and also add controls to directly (meaning not thru iOS settings) alter tts parameters (speed, etc.), I will have to use AVSpeechSynthesizer instead of relying on the built-in VoiceOver.

Comment: VoiceOver users can alter the speed of the readout. This is a feature of VoiceOver, built in. Only utilize AVSpeechSynthesizer if it would also be used by normal customers NEVER user AVSpeechSynthesizer to override default Accessibility features. This is a nasty can of worms. It also seems to me like you (or your test team) could familiarize themselves with VoiceOVer more thoroughly. Many of the "core issues" you're trying to solve (reading between the lines), are things that VoiceOver does by default, if you understand how to use it properly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand it, you can not put a control in your app that can alter VoiceOver readout speed---this has to be done in iOS settings. My client wants direct control from the app. It is also not possible to track readout progress with built-in VoiceOver---this is also a must have for my client.

Comment: Just because your client wants it, doesn't mean it's a good idea. Your client has correctly identified problems VoiceOver users may have using such an application. What they have failed to identify, is that advanced settings of VoiceOver solve these problems already, and that overriding these settings with in App nonsense is absolutely NOT the correct thing to do from a VoiceOver user's perspective. See my profile for my credentials when it comes to Accessibility.