# iOS Accessibility Voice over mode get the tapped line/pragraph content

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, pdfkit

I am developing a PDF viewer app, it uses `PDFKit` as a library. I create a view contain a PDFView, and load the custom view in a `UIViewController` subclass.

Now I am foused on accessibility voice over, what I can get from `PDFView` class in `PDFKit` is `currentPage` or `visiablePages`, but I find that other iOS apps can read the **paragrah or line** where I tapped in the page, it looks more detailed. So I can let the speaker to read the whole visiable page contents or current page content. I wonder anyone know how can I get the line or paragraph content/frame information about user the position user clicks?

PS I guess maybe it has something to do with accessibilityTraits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VoiceOver in UITextView: read paragraph at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285259/voiceover-in-uitextview-read-paragraph-at-a-time)

Comment: If you believe your circumstance isn't a duplicate of the question above, try and be a little more specific. From my point of view, the answer in that post answers this question completely.

Comment: Thank you for your help. at last I find a cheating answer, actually the PDFKit library I use it supports it, but I need to add the PDFView from code not directly added it in xib file.